# Using Coalesce in a SQL query

Tags: sql, mariadb

How do I default the product_costs.amount to 0 if there is no product_costs.amount found where the product_costs.start_date is less than the product_revenue.start_date.

I have  created a fiddle here with a create script and query below https://dbfiddle.uk/PM2nCk5R

The query is as below;

```
SELECT
   YEAR(product_revenues.revenue_date) AS revenueYear,
    MONTH(product_revenues.revenue_date) AS revenueMonth,
    SUM(product_revenues.amount) AS totalRevenue,
    COALESCE(SUM(product_costs.amount), 0)  AS totalCost,
    SUM(product_revenues.amount - COALESCE(product_costs.amount, 0)) AS totalProfit
    FROM product_revenues
    LEFT JOIN product_costs
       ON product_costs.start_date <= product_revenues.revenue_date
       AND product_costs.start_date = (
         SELECT MAX(start_date)
         FROM product_costs
         WHERE start_date <= product_revenues.revenue_date
        )
     WHERE product_revenues.team_id = 1
     AND product_costs.team_id =1
     AND product_revenues.stripe_product_id ='prod_1234'
     AND product_costs.stripe_product_id ='prod_1234'
     AND product_revenues.revenue_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12  MONTH AND NOW()
     GROUP BY revenueMonth, revenueYear
     ORDER BY revenueMonth ASC;
```

The tables are

### Product Costs

| id | team_id | amount | stripe_product_id | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 | prod_1234 | 2023-08-01 |

### Product Revenue table

| id | team_id | amount | stripe_product_id | revenue_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 | prod_1234 | 2023-07-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 1000 | prod_1234 | 2023-09-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 | prod_1234 | 2023-10-01 |

### Expected result

| revenueYear | revenueMonth | totalRevenue | totalCost | totalProfit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 07 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| 2023 | 09 | 1000 | 600 | 400 |
| 2023 | 10 | 1000 | 600 | 400 |

So revenue id 1 has no cost because there is not cost record earlier than it. But id 2 and 3 will be attributed to cost id 1. I thought left join returns all records but my query is constraining to return only  2 and 3 revenue id.

Comment: If you reference the LEFT JOIN table in your WHERE clause then it effectively turns it into an INNER JOIN. You probably need to move these type of conditions into your JOIN clause

Comment: Oh dear! I lost so many hours on this. Thanks @NickW I moved all the  "AND product_costs..." into the inner join and it worked. Happy to accept an answer if you want to post as an answer

Comment: Presumably you'll need the same condition in that "max" subquery as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference the LEFT JOIN table in your WHERE clause then it effectively turns it into an INNER JOIN. You probably need to move these type of conditions into your JOIN clause

Comment: ;.. except if the test is for `NULL` or `NOT NULL`